# Polymorphic relationships OneToMany on Laravel Backpack

Tags: polymorphism, laravel-backpack

I have some troubles in a Polymorphic OneToMany relationship.
Here is the scenario :

I have 3 entities : Offers, Sectors, Services
All of them can have multiple steps. Models are OK but I have some trouble in how to use widget to create the form. I want to have a form which give the possibility to the user to choose which type of entity is linked to the step and which entity is used.

Here are my models

```
// Same models for Service and Sector

Class Offer extends Model
{
    // Fillable are OK

    public function steps()
    {
        return $this->morphMany(Step::class, 'stepable');
    }
}
```

```
Class Step extends Model
{
    // Fillable are OK

    public function stepable()
    {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }
}
```

Simple OneToMany polymorphic ... But I really don't know how to do my form to create this kind of relation.
ManyToMany relationships like "taggable" case is OK to me but I don't succeed in this one :(

Thanks a lot for all your help.

Mamat